# Is there a list of phone numbers Facebook uses to send auth tokens?

Tags: authentication, sms, facebook

Up to a few days ago, I always received Facebook auth tokens from numbers `+181338477XX`, except a few times from `+85294985XXX`.

Problem is that lately I've been receiving codes directly from Italian numbers, which wouldn't be strange since I'm located in Italy, but there are two odd things:

1.
they are much much slower than before, i.e. may take easily 2~15 minutes, while before they were instant

2.
they are badly formatted, not exactly with spelling mistakes like the typical phishing mail, but oddly they add random characters in the text (examples follow)

Regular message:

- `Il tuo codice di sicurezza di Facebook: XXXXXX`

Odd messages:

- +393460286641 `Il,tuo codice'di sicurezza di Facebook: XXXXXX`
- +393774919485 `Il tuo codice di,sicurezza_di Facebook: XXXXXX'`
- +393428446457 `Il tuo codice,di sicurezza di Facebook: XXXXXX,`
- +393385643500 `Il tuo,codice di sicurezza_di Facebook: XXXXXX.`
- +393806332520 `Il,tuo codice,di sicurezza di Facebook: XXXXXX`

---

edit for some new SMS:

- +393455720151 `Usa 033985'come_password per Facebook Messenger for.Android.`
- +393402647316 `Usa 033985 come password'per Facebook Messenger for Android._`
- +393456388686 `Usa 808589 come password per Facebook for Android.'`
- +393484224323 `Usa 808589 come password per.Facebook for.Android.`

*(these are different because it's not the web login but the Android app logins, but still weird characters appear)*

I have two phone numbers bound to that FB account. Previously I logged only the message of one of those phones. Now instead o logged them on both phones, and it is interesting to notice how even the "same" message was corrupted in different ways.

---

The first odd thing is those random characters (so far `,`,`'`,`_`,`.`) either between two words or at the end of the string, and the second odd thing is that the phone numbers are always totally different, while before they were using only two "main" numbers, with many "sub" numbers (pardon the made-up terms).

I'm totally clueless about *who* could do such a thing such as hijacking `SMS`s, *why* corrupt the messages this way, and why do that and *not* use it: i.e. looking at the logins, authorised devices, etc. there wasn't anything unusual.

A final oddity has happened the first time we received such a message: there are two phones bound for these auth tokens, and only one of those received the strange message, while the other one received the correct one (both were delayed, though).

Comment: I can't find any official list of phone numbers FB is using for their 2FA, but that might be beyond the point, as spoofing `Sender ID` with arbitrary alphanumeric text isn't all that difficult. I can't prove it either way with the information you provide and access I have (which probably goes the same for anyone here except @JeffFerland), but you say it yourself everything else seems legit besides the strange formatting, so I doubt it's an attack. And [it wouldn't be the first time FB has _problems_ with 2FA](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150172618258920) either (check comments).

Comment: Facebook recently had an account hijacking vulnerability reported to them, exploiting their SMS service. Worth having a look if it is related with your issue. grahamcluley.com/2013/06/hack-facebook-sms

Comment: @Moustache while it's somehow related, it's not that, since the connected phone numbers and the approved devices are the correct ones, apparently...

Comment: I'm working on finding an answer to this. Given it's the end of this week and a major American holiday is next week, it may take a while to discover.

Comment: Just checking in to let you know this is still winding its way through, but at least I've got the right person on it now.

Comment: @JeffFerland great! I've received a couple of new odd SMS just today, I'll edit the post to add them

Comment: One should point out if the code is correct, and Facebook accepts it, then its not really possible for it to not be from Facebook.

Comment: @Ramhound in theory it might be a man-in-the-middle attack, though it doesn't really make sense because they wouldn't alter the message that way of course.

Comment: @Lohoris - Whats the point of forwarding the actual code, if its a man-in-the-middle attack, just send a fake one.  At that point you already have control of the account.

Comment: @Ramhound as I said, I'm clueless about this. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @JeffFerland both today and on 7th Oct I've received normal messages. Has this been actively fixed, or it "just works" and we don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

The sms vulnerability reported to Facebook was something else as far as I saw, it uses the Facebook's response to unregistered numbers to receive an unused confirmation code to reset password of other users...

If you are using an Android device, I strongly suggest you should check your mobile for any malicious applications. While I was doing some research on Mobile security, I came across some applications that could steal information from device. This happens when you install application from third-party sites other than Google Play. Some of them are really strong that, they are capable of even updating themselves while an upgrade of OS is made (eg: JB-KitKat)

I am not sure about the possibility of MITM, because, who in the hell want to intercept a response code and add weirdness to the message? And even if someone is intercepting you, they wont just send those messages to you because from my belief, once a token is used it expires, so if they use it, you wont be able to use it.

My opinion is that, every now or then FB makes roll outs , try new features, They might had tried some kind of localization on the sms/login-token features.

If only one of your phone numbers have only this problem, you may also have to consider the possibility of a fault from service provider.